# How to disconnect ActionCable connection inside a Channel Controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there any way to disconnect ActionCable from a Channel Controller?

I've tried to `return` from the `subscribed` method but it did not close the connection

```rb
class MyChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    ####
    return unless condition
    ####
    stream_from "mychannel_#{params[:id]}"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way using `reject`

```rb
class MyChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    ####
    unless condition do
      reject
      return
    end
    ####
    stream_from "mychannel_#{params[:id]}"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end
end
```